# Section name in the Header (Amsart)

Tags: amsart, section-titles

I want to put the name of the section (and preferably the name of the subsection) at the header of the page. I've used this code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\setlength\headsep{15pt}
\setlength\footskip{25pt}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{0in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % choose the "fancy" pagestyle
\fancyhf{}        % clear all headers and footers
% Now set the headers
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\footnotesize\leftmark}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@sect}{\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}}{}{}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
 text

\newpage
\section{section II}
text

\end{document}
```

But the problem that I've got is described in the attached photo:

[image: 1]

1. Next to the introduction, there is the number 2 instead of having
   the number 1.

[image: 2]

2. There is an offset from the margin here and I don't know how I can
   fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the header definitions and added some dummy text to see how they play.

[image: e]

[image: f]

If you want to use `\newpage` you need to "reset" the headings. For example use `\newpage \thispagestyle{plain}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\setlength\headsep{15pt}
\setlength\footskip{25pt}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}
\setlength\evensidemargin{0in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}   

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@sect}{\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}}{}{}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

1.  \kant[1-7]  

\section{Section II}

2.  \kant[3-8]
    
\end{document}
```